# kismet on raspberry pi failed ./configure libwebsockets

Tags: raspbian, libwebsockets, kismet-wireless

The step before doing the 'make' requires the `./config`.  It is failing with the following

```
checking for libwebsockets... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libwebsockets >= 3.2.0) were not met:

Requested 'libwebsockets >= 3.2.0' but version of libwebsockets is 2.0.3

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libwebsockets_CFLAGS
and libwebsockets_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have done the following
https:///www.kismetwireless.net/get/kismet.git>
`git clone --recursive`

how do i get a more recent version?

i can see that there is 4.0.20 but it is shown as testing/unstable

https://repology.org/project/libwebsockets/versions

and even if that is OK do i do a wget/get/curl with what parameters in what directory.  I really need guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can also disable libwebsockets when running configure:

> ./configure --disable-libwebsockets

compiling without it will not remove websockets from the Kismet server, or prevent using websockets, but any remote capture code compiled without libwebsockets will only be able to use the legacy TCP connection mode (taken from kismet site)

Answer (score 2):

Download the libwebsockets source code from here: https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/releases/tag/v3.2.3

Unzip it:

`tar -xvzf v3.2.2.3.tar.gz`

Install `cmake`:

`sudo apt-get install cmake -y`

Compile `libwebsockets`:

```
cd libwebsockets-3.2.3
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make && sudo make install
```

Then retry `./configure` for Kismet installation.